# Jersey WADL: How do you rename generated XSDs

Tags: java, xsd, jersey, wadl

The web service I am working on has the generated WADL that Jersey creates. What I want to do is rename xsd0.xsd to Result.xsd or something like that. When it regenerates the WADL every time, it will be Result.xsd. Is this possible with Jersey?

Answer (score 4):

[The source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/wadl/internal/generators/WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator.java#L376) has hard-coded `counter++` thing in a very private method, so you cannot change it easliy. But as I see, you could create your own wadl generator implemenation and configure with it `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties#WADL_GENERATOR_CONFIG` property, then you could do custom naming code.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I find some on how to configure my own implementation?

Comment: @lmsasu Take the jersey-samples, it has `extended-wadl-webapp` in it. The `SampleWadlGeneratorConfig` could be changed to something like: `return generator( MyWadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator.class )`. You could create the generator class by copying the original one from the link above. When you could customise it.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow [this](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/HowToConfigureExtendedWADL) and modify the application-grammars.xml file to this

```
<grammars xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XML/xinclude">
   <include href="Result.xsd" />
</grammars>
```

you could add another grammar, Result.xsd in your case, into the wadl but **not replace** the xsd0.xsd